# How to change the content Pane of a JFrame with a slide-in or fade-in effect

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, sliding

I have two JPanel `a` and `b`.By default `a` is set as ContentPane.Jpanel `a` has a button on it which when clicked changes contentPane to panel `b`.But I want it to panel 'b' to slideIn or fade-In smoothly instead of sudden change.

Here is the code (in case necessary)

```
class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel a,b;
    JButton button;
    GUI()
    {
        super("Sliding Layout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        button=new JButton("Slide");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        a=new JPanel();
        a.setBackground(Color.RED);
        a.add(button);

        b=new JPanel();
        b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        b.add(new JLabel("New Content Pane"));
        setSize(800,400);
        setContentPane(a);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        button.setText("Changed");
        //what should I do here to change the contentPane to panel 'b' with green color 
        //with either slide-in-from -right or fade-in effect?
    }
}
```

After searching I found that **Universal Tween Engine** and **Sliding Layout** are two possible options.But Sliding Layout is I suppose based on Changing the grid cells but I want to change entire contentPane.So **Tween Engine** is the option but I tried to understand about an hour but no success.

I have attached the jars to my project.Can anyone of you please provide a code snippet or exact tutorial.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html approach. It's based on `CardLayout` extension.

Comment: :Exactly what I wanted.But still waiting for the answer related to Tween Engine as it provides more options and effects. +1

Comment: But the problem is that I have to keep those buttons always,I suppose.What if I want to come to home page from another page.

Comment: You can add one more card when you need and slide to the new one.

Comment: I found another similar approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283554/slide-effect-with-jpanel . Is using this approach expected to produce flickers if suppose I had complex Panel with images and other components.